# Unable to deploy REST based Node.js APP on heroku

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, rest, heroku

I build a Node.js REST implementation using this [tutorial](http://thejackalofjavascript.com/architecting-a-restful-node-js-app/) .And now i am having problems deploying it on heoroku , local works fine .

Heroku logs :

[image]

> I believe the problem is with my directory structure. The "main" key
>   of package.json and and the rest endpoints in index.js are not right

Next I was successfully able to deploy my app on **Heroku** but I am getting the  error.My implementation is as follows :

> **EDIT :**  I removed the Procfile ,  compared to shown in following pics ,as I added the "start" key in package.json

**Local :**

[image]

Directory Structure -  /webapp is the root directory : 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

> I have package.json file  at root directory and /server with different
>   version (about which i am not sure how they should be actually for my
>   **ngClient** and heroku confiurations )

Files contents of root , /webapp :
package.json

```
  {
      "name": "web_first_package",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "description": "first node package for project storm",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "start":"/myRESTApp/server/server.js"
      },
    "engines": {
        "node": "6.9.x",
        "npm": "3.10.x"
      },

      "author": "Divyanshu Jimmy",
      "license": "ISC",
      "dependencies": {
        "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
        "express": "^4.14.0",
        "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
        "morgan": "^1.7.0"
      }
    }
```

package.json in /myRESTApp/server:

```
{
  "name": "web_first_package",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "first node package for project storm",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.9.x",
    "npm": "3.10.x"
  },
  "author": "Divyanshu Jimmy",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.15.2",
    "express": "^4.14.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "morgan": "^1.7.0"
  }
}
```

> Node version : 6.9.2 NPM Version : 3.10.9

Comment: Try using this path in start script `./myRESTApp/server/server.js`. You missed the dot.

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi you meant in value for key "start" in package.json of root dirdctory ?

Comment: Having two package.json would do you no good. Only first package.json would be processed (which is in outer folder).

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi if i will delete inner package.json then to test in my local i need to run nodemon from root directory ?

Comment: yes, package.json of root dirdctory.

Comment: you can run nodemon from anywhere. did it work after changing the path?

Comment: no it didnt worked , please see edited question for logs

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi do i need to change the path for main key in package.json ?

Comment: nah, heroku runs the start script for the application. In the edited question there was no error description. Can you look for the error, it may be somewhere down in the logs.

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi i moved conversation to chat and also ediited complete error log

Comment: also after changing the package.json, you'll need to commit the changes and then push them to heroku repository. Did you do this? You can refer to this [tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-deploy-a-node-js-app-to-heroku)

Comment: I did both commit and push to heroku, editted my answer with node and npm version

Comment: can you attach your server.js file?

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi i have edited question qwith server.js content

Comment: did you configure dyno while deploying the app?

Comment: @RitikSaxena yes i do configured

Comment: @Softxide Change start script to `node ./myRESTApp/server/server.js`.

Comment: @Softxide did it work?

Comment: @AnuragAwasthi It worked , can you please explain your solution. I missed adding node and ./ to start key

Comment: @Softxide Sorry, I should have seen it earlier. You can define different scripts in scripts section of package.json for ease. In addition to start we can have `buid`, `test` and other scripts. These scripts should be valid npm commands. You can search `npm srcipts` for more info.

Comment: thx , rest endpoints are working but i cant load my views

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change start script to `node ./myRESTApp/server/server.js`.

Comment: My rest endpoints are working but i am unable to load my angularjs views